# Setting Fonts in Android using an external XML File

Tags: android, xml

I have a text view field in which I want to use cursive.  However I want to call this from an external xml file so I can use the font created in external file at multiple places.

If I do this in my **homescreen.xml** it works fine

```
android:fontFamily="cursive"
```

I am trying the following but is not working

**homescreen.xml**

```
android:fontFamily="@font/font_name1"
```

**fonts.xml**

```
<resources>
      <font name="font_name1">cursive</font>
</resources>
```

Comment: as I am reading I find that it is not like CSS or HTML/PHP where you can name anything, keep it anywhere you like and call it... Android Studio is rigid in the way it does things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**homescreen.xml**

```
 android:fontFamily="@string/font_family3"
```

**Values->fonts.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string name="font_family1">sans-serif-thin</string>
    <string name="font_family2">cursive</string>
    <string name="font_family3">sans-serif-condensed</string>
</resources>
```